# page cookies in puppeteer not work for keep login

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer

i want make a web scraper on https://web.whatsapp.com
for sending message to my customers
i want save my login for next use that no need to re-scan the qr-code
i know that i have to save cookie and set in for next use
after scan qr and login to my account i see cookie in google chrome dev tools,application tab and cookie section but page.cookie is empty and return []
I tried to store cookies in a file using a sample code.after running code mycookie.json created and [] is in.

how can do it?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--start-maximized']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36');
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
    await page.goto('https://web.whatsapp.com/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1440,
        height: 900
    });
    await page.waitFor(10000);//wait for scan qr
    console.log(await page.cookies());

    // Save Session Cookies
    var cookiesFilePath = 'mycookie.json';
    const cookiesObject = await page.cookies();
    // Write cookies to temp file to be used in other profile pages
    jsonfile.writeFile(cookiesFilePath, cookiesObject, { spaces: 2 },
     function(err) { 
      if (err) {
      console.log('The file could not be written.', err)
      }
      console.log('Session has been successfully saved')
    })
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **userDataDir** If you use that you won't lose your browser data.
Even if you get cookie data that won't help you because web WhatsApp uses **local-storage** as well.

**Example**

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: false,
     args: ['--start-maximized'],
     userDataDir: '<PATH>' // './cache' for example   
});
```

*The directory defined in the PATH variable must exist!*

**References**
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#puppeteerdefaultargsoptions

https://docs.browserless.io/blog/2019/05/03/improving-puppeteer-performance.html#launch-with-a-user-data-dir

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md